# apache2.4 (debian11): access of /.htm or /.html sites lead to 403 (and not 404)

Tags: apache-2.4, apache2

If I install apache2 on debian 11 and access one of the following urls:

http://localhost/.htm

http://localhost/.html

I don't get the expected HTTP status-code 404, I get a HTTP-status code 403 instead!

However, if I access the url http://localhost/.abc I get HTTP-status code 404.

Does anyone know, why apache returns 403 and not 404 for the not existing `./.htm` and `./.html` files?

I did not change any config-files, thus the config should be the default config shipped with debian 11!
The virtualhost-config is the default debian virtualhost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Apache config contains the following snippet by default:

```
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being          
# viewed by Web clients.                                                        
#                                                                               
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

It's pretty well explained by the comment. `.htaccess` and `.htpasswd` are files that can contain security relevant configuration, and be present in the web root. Thus the default config simply blocks files starting with `.ht`.